# Using Makefile.am and Makefil.in Windows 7?

Tags: makefile

I've search other posts and I apologize if this is  a stupid question...but I have some source code I'm wanting to compile. One folder has a Makefile.am and Makefile.in that I'm assuming I need to use, but cannot figure out how. Any recommendations?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some version of GNU Automake

An introduction to automake is found in wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automake

Automake can be installed in windows.

Simple Summary:

Makefile.am , Makefile.in and config.h.in all combine through the magic of Perl and the M4 macro preprocessor.

Course of attack:

get a perl installation
get the autotools for windows installation

once it's all installed , invoke ./configure and bob's your uncle, you get a makefile.

This is the historical source of this stanza of unix script activity

```
{if no configure.in}
    #.autoscan
{if no ./configure}
    #.autoconf

#./configure
#make
#make install
```

And once you have all the tools installed , you can do it too.

Comment: Again..sorry for bothering. But I'm in mingw32 and cd to the relevant directory with the files seen above but ./configure just sends back sh: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Assuming you have no configure script, if you don't have a config.in you'll need to do #autoscan #autoconf see amended answer